# Putting my own tables in ASP.net Identity Framework Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

So I'm creating a web app and using code first for the database. I want to use ASP identity.

I get how you have to send a post to create a user and then the tables are automatically generated in a database. What I want to know his how do I get my tables to generate there too. I have classes modeled and I created my context but that's where I'm stuck.

How do I set up my tables so everything is generated into one database?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `DbContext` implement [`IdentityDbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext(v=vs.108).aspx). That way, your custom tables will be added in the same context as the default identity tables.

Ie.

```
public CustomDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
}
```